# Trouble with spokes/bracketed cone

Tags: modeling

I'm quite new to blender, and I'm making assets for a game, but ran into issues when making a bazooka. The model can be fairly low poly.

There is a fire guard (cage?) on the back of the bazooka (see image) that I just cannot figure out how to approach.

[image]

The closest I've gotten is using a basic cone shape (which just does not capture that look and feel). I've also tried to put a circle, extruding lines from it and then merging the objects after applying a skin modifier and bevel, well the look just turns garbled (see image)
[image]

I already have the rest of the cylinder for the bazooka tube and most of the rest of the object finished.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by low-poly, can it be square shapes or does it need to be round?

Comment: Skin can do it: just lower the vertices radius (in edit mode, n, item, transform, meanradius).

Comment: Thanks all I was able to get the solution using the torus + cylinder and array modifier combination.

Answer (score 1):

I used a torus primitive to make the circle, and a cylinder to make one spoke. I put a couple of loop cuts in the cylinder and rotated it to get the cone shape. An array modifier set to object and an empty rotated 72° turn the single cylinder into 5 spokes.

[image: Result]
[image: Wireframe]

Comment: Thank you very much! After some consternation figuring out that I had to also place the cursor at the origin, I was able to replicate yours. Honestly very helpful, and while I need to get learned on array modifiers it was the direction to take.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it very low-poly, you can create a 18 vertex cylinder like that:

[image]

Duplicate:

[image]

Extrude a face of the top cylinder:

[image]

Join the extrusion with the bottom cylinder:

[image]

Only keep 3 segments of the object, then duplicate, rotate around the center and merge by distance:

[image]

[image]

If you need to round the object, create a 36/6 vertex torus:

[image]

Cut a hole, extrude and make a circle with *LoopTools*:

[image]

Extrude down:

[image]

Create a cylinder at the bottom, join the 2 shape with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

[image]

Only keep 6 segments of the mesh:

[image]

Duplicate and rotate around the center, merge by distance:

[image]

Rework the topology a bit, shade smooth:

[image]

Comment: I took a stab using the first comment and found success, but really wanted to thank you for walking me through another strategy!